# Why text starts a new line in li tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have drop down menu which i created with the "ul" and "li" tags.But my text in the li tag starts a new line at every space in it.Here's the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiureznicencu/w5uemy1s/) to the code.

```js
 var a=document.getElementById("hide");
var outside="false";

function showjs(){
    if(visibil()==="false"){
 a.style.display="inline-block";   

    }
}

function hidejs(){
    if(visibil()==="true" & outside==="true"){
     a.style.display="none";   
    }
}

function visibil(){
    if (a.style.display==="none"){
       return "false";
    }else{
    return "true";   
    }
}
```

```css
ul{
    list-style:none;

}
li{
    position:relative
}

.cl-menu,ul{
    margin:0;padding:0
}
.cl-menu li a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px
}
#menu{
    background-color:gray;
    width:20%;
}
/*li:active>ul{
    display:block;
}*/
li>ul{
    
    background-color:black
}
```

```html
<body onclick="hidejs()">
<div id='menu'>
 <ul class="cl-menu">
  <li>
   <a href="#">Mis pedidos</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Mi perfil</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Descuentos</a>
  </li>
  <li id='albumes' onclick="showjs()" style="background-color:gray" onmouseleave="outside='true';" onmouseenter="outside='false';">
   <a href="#">Albumes</a>
   <ul id="hide" style="display:none;position:absolute; top:0;left:100%;">
    <li style="color:white">
     <a href="#">Here are generated new lines at every space</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Navidad 2014</a>
    </li>
   </ul> 
        </li>
   <li>
   <a href="#">Añadir al carrito</a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href="#">Articulos seleccionados</a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href="#">Finalizar Pedido</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

So, I don't want those new lines and if it possible to be resolved without setting the width.Thank you.

Comment: this only occurs because you set a width, the width you set for `#menu` constrains the width of your `li`...

Comment: What do you want to happen instead of wrapping? Should the `#menu` get wider?

Comment: I removed the width and is the same problem!

Comment: @sergiureznicencu [How so?](http://jsfiddle.net/w5uemy1s/2/) Only if the browser window is too narrow to fit the text...

Comment: [showdev]: Not #menu.Only the black menu(with id="hide")

Comment: If you don't want `#menu` to expand, then [the text can go outside of `#menu`](http://jsfiddle.net/w5uemy1s/3/). Is that the desired result?

Comment: I think i got the solution.I removed the width and then i set the display to inline block. Someone answered.

Comment: @sergiureznicencu Please tick mark the answer that helped you solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `white-space:nowrap` to the text and add `display:inline-block` to the menu

```js
var a=document.getElementById("hide");
var outside="false";

function showjs(){
    if(visibil()==="false"){
 a.style.display="inline-block";   

    }
}

function hidejs(){
    if(visibil()==="true" & outside==="true"){
     a.style.display="none";   
    }
}

function visibil(){
    if (a.style.display==="none"){
       return "false";
    }else{
    return "true";   
    }
}
```

```css
ul{
    list-style:none;

}
li{
    position:relative
}

.cl-menu,ul{
    margin:0;padding:0
}
.cl-menu li a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px
}
#menu{
    background-color:gray;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*li:active>ul{
    display:block;
}*/
li>ul{
    
    background-color:black
}

li a{
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<body onclick="hidejs()">
<div id='menu'>
 <ul class="cl-menu">
  <li>
   <a href="#">Mis pedidos</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Mi perfil</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Descuentos</a>
  </li>
  <li id='albumes' onclick="showjs()" style="background-color:gray" onmouseleave="outside='true';" onmouseenter="outside='false';">
   <a href="#">Albumes</a>
   <ul id="hide" style="display:none;position:absolute; top:0;left:100%;">
    <li style="color:white">
     <a href="#">Here are generated new lines at every space</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Navidad 2014</a>
    </li>
   </ul> 
        </li>
   <li>
   <a href="#">Añadir al carrito</a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href="#">Articulos seleccionados</a>
  </li>
   <li>
   <a href="#">Finalizar Pedido</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Set display:inline-block and delete the width in the menu

Answer (score 1):

Add this rule:

```
#hide a {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/w5uemy1s/1/)**

Comment: But then the text goes outside the `#menu`.